# truffle compile , truffle test or truffle migration does not show any console output or exception . It just do nothing

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I am setting up truffle with my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and VS Code, getting  follwowing truffle [quickstart](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/quickstart)

However, the truffle compile or truffle migrate or truffle test does not work. Even it does not throw any exception. Anybody faced the similar issue?

truffle compile is not working. When I run the command it simply returns even its not showing any error.
truffle init is working properly so that truffle istallation is not an issue. But truffle compile and migrate commands having issue.
How can I fix this on Ubuntu machine??

Truffle v5.0.4 (core: 5.0.4)

Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)

Node v8.10.0

Comment: use sudo if you're on Linux
eg. sudo truffle compile

Answer (score 0):

After burning two nights, I have realized that truffle 5.0.4 is not stable yet. For which truffle compile, build or migrate does not function even it does not throw any exception.

I have uninstalled the truffle 5.0.4 and installed the Truffle v5.0.0-next.26 (core: 5.0.0-beta.2) and it starts working.

abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ which truffle 
/usr/local/bin/truffle
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ rm -r /usr/local/bin/truffle
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/truffle': Permission denied
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/truffle
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ which truffle 
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ sudo npm uninstall -g truffle
removed 91 packages in 3.35s
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ truffle --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/truffle: No such file or directory
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ truffle --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/truffle: No such file or directory
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ sudo npm install -g truffle@5.0.0-next.26
/usr/local/bin/truffle -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js

> keccak@1.4.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
>   npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."
>
> keccak@1.4.0 rebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
>   node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.
+ truffle@5.0.0-next.26
added 91 packages from 305 contributors in 30.464s
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ sudo npm install -g truffle@5.0.0-next.26
/usr/local/bin/truffle -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@5.0.0-next.26
updated 1 package in 4.731s
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ sudo npm install -g truffle@5.0.0-next.26
/usr/local/bin/truffle -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@5.0.0-next.26
updated 1 package in 4.075s
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ truffle version
Truffle v5.0.0-next.26 (core: 5.0.0-beta.2)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v8.10.0
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ truffle init

✔ Preparing to download

✔ Downloading

✔ Cleaning up temporary files

✔ Setting up box

Unbox successful. Sweet!

Commands:

Compile:        truffle compile
  Migrate:        truffle migrate
  Test contracts: truffle test

abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ truffle compile
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ truffle build
No build configuration found. Preparing to compile contracts.
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ truffle migrate
⚠️  Important ⚠️
If you're using an HDWalletProvider, it must be Web3 1.0 enabled or your migration will hang.
Try: npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider@web3-one

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'ganache'
>   Network id:      5777
>   Block gas limit: 6721975

## 1_initial_migration.js

Deploying 'Migrations'

---

> transaction hash:    0x393caf519758cb8baf13ee100d5a0a08e329674d77489888f61833aa83cdb5d9
>   Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
>   contract address:    0xC2d9c21b93d3D29b9ac03697CAc058FdA432Ce98
>   account:             0xA0d939f21C2d714754EB7a3091545B5C423EE18E
>   balance:             99.99430184
>   gas used:            284908
>   gas price:           20 gwei
>   value sent:          0 ETH
>   total cost:          0.00569816 ETH
>
> Saving migration to chain.
>   Saving artifacts
>
> ---
>
> Total cost:          0.00569816 ETH

## Summary

> Total deployments:   1
>   Final cost:          0.00569816 ETH

abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ touch contracts/Election.sol
abdus@abdus-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/election$ truffle build
No build configuration found. Preparing to compile contracts.
Compiling ./contracts/Election.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts